# PHP to return 1x1 transparent GIF, how is this data encoded?

Tags: php, image, header, http-headers

I have seen this [web beacon image here](http://www.desilva.biz/php/beacon.html)

The code looks like this:

```
header( 'Content-type: image/gif' );
# The transparent, beacon image
echo chr(71).chr(73).chr(70).chr(56).chr(57).chr(97).
     chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(128).chr(0).
     chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).
     chr(33).chr(249).chr(4).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).
     chr(0).chr(0).chr(44).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).
     chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).chr(2).chr(2).
     chr(68).chr(1).chr(0).chr(59);
```

And that made it very easy to let PHP return a transparent GIF-image. However, if I want to change the image, how can I do it? How do I transform any GIF that i create to this format?

Thanks.

Comment: Open your gif in any hex-viewer and copy it byte to byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better than doing that, after you set a cookie or add a log entry, you can just redirect the call to an actual image (be it gif/jpeg/etc) and let the webserver worry about sending the content etc:

```
header("Location: http://webserver.com/images/beacon.gif");
```

Comment: Needs a  heap more cache-control headers if the pixel is intended for page counting.

Comment: agree -- though his question wasn't about that it seems but rather how to return the image.

Comment: This makes an extra full HTTP request to get the file, which takes up both network and web server resources. It's extra bad if there's a lot of other resources (like JS and stylesheets) which can't be fetched due to the browser limit on simultaneous TCP connections. In that case, those resources will have to wait an extra round-trip time over the network.

Comment: however, it offloads the caching of the actual pixel content onto the webserver! so if you set your headers right in the actual pixel call such that this doesn't get cached then you can allow for the image call itself to allow caching of the bytes -- in which case really there will be just a HTTP HEAD executed.

Comment: True, so this solution may be the best if you set expire headers on the image file (so it expires in the future). Another way could be to use my solution and also read If-Modified-Since headers sent by the web browser (in which case both our solutions will produce the same result and have similar performance).

Comment: Interesting solution indeed, with the correct caching-headers of the second image.

Comment: @Emil: Can you expand on the using of If-Modified-Since header together with your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just have the image in a file and let PHP read and return it?

```
header('Content-type: image/gif');
readfile('file.gif');
```

If you really want to convert the image to PHP code, read it one byte at a time and create the PHP code like this:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('file.gif', 'r');
$i = 0;
echo 'echo ';
while(!feof($fh)) {
  $byte = fread($fh, 1);
  $num = ord($byte);
  echo 'chr(', $num, ')';
  if(!feof($fh)) {
    echo '.'; //there's more bytes, echo dot                                    
    if(++$i % 6 == 0) {
      echo "\n     "; //do not be too wide                                      
    }
  }
}
echo ";\n";
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: if you're going to go down this route, then it's definitely not optimal to read the file on each request (think of the disk access involved!). I would suggest reading this image in this case on first request and caching it in memory for subsequent requests so you don't have to go to the disk each time

Comment: Liv, the file will be cached in RAM by the OS kernel. There's no need to reinvent that caching. Actually, it's probably faster to run my first solution with readfile than creating a file with numerous calls to chr() (context switch!).

Comment: while that is true you overestimate the os file caching.The reality is fopen() will still be executed and the kernel will prepare all the internal structures for the file so disk access for that will still happen. it's only at the point of fread the os caching will kick in and return you the data from memory. fclose again will require disk access (last accessed timestamp!)

Comment: You may be correct, but I can't see why this should be any different from your solution. Also, atime is disabled by all sane sysadmins.